# slideDown callback выполняется много раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть jQuery-объект block, состоящий из нескольких элементов. К объекту применяется функция slideDown(), после выполнения которой, для всех элементов объекта должно произойти действие. Привожу пример кода, отражающего суть:

```
var block = $('.class');
var length = block.length //35
block.slideDown(500, function () {
  console.log('done');
});
```

В итоге 'done' выводится 35 раз, как сделать так чтобы выводилось 1 раз, после выполнения slideDown() для всех блоков?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var block = $('.class');

$.when(block.slideDown(500)).then(function() {
  console.log('done');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
<div class="class"></div>
```

Comment: ну наплюсовали то. ответ не верный) выполняется сразу, не работает со slideDown, при этом с fadeIn например работает

Answer (score 1):

Возможно есть какой-то более логичный вариант, но с ходу в голову не пришел:

```
var block = $('.class');
var length = block.length //35

block.each(function( i ) {
  $(this).eq(i).slideDown(500, function () {
    if(i + 1 === length) console.log('done');
  });
});
```

Ну или так:

```
var block = $('.class');
var length = block.length //35

block.slideDown(500, function () {
  if($(this).index() + 1 === length) console.log('done');
});
```